# Why should I "walk quietly in the hallway"?

Tags: super-mario-64

So I was playing Super Mario 64 on an emulator, and something really bugged me.

> Shhh! Please walk
>   quietly in the hallway!
>
> <sub>— Sign, Super Mario 64</sub>

Is there some secrets or easter eggs here? I tried to keep silent by not moving, crawling, walking slowly and also make loud noise by pounding the ground but nothing happened.

[image: Shhh! Please walk quietly in the hallway!]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no particular easter egg to see here, however the explanation to it can be found here:

> On the second floor of the castle, affixed to the wall adjoining the steps that lead to the door that requires 50 Power Stars to enter, is a plaque that reads:
>   "Shhh! Please walk quietly in the hallway!"
>
> Possibly answered in the remake, where Toad says this to Wario:
>
> "Wario, it's impolite to shuffle noisily around the castle, you know. No matter how tough you look... it's...umm...prohibited."
>
> While that doesn't explain much, maybe he was referring to the sign as justification to complain about Wario's behaviour here, so it's given a sort of mysterious, new reason to exist in the remake/Mario 64 DS.

Taken from Chrisjh0223 from http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/198848-super-mario-64/44157242?page=10

Comment: there's really a secret, is not something scary, my brother spawn a little bird in that corridor, but I cant spawn him again

Comment: @KeindelArgos This is not true at all.